# Python how to delete a specific value from a dictionary key with multiple values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with multiple values per key and each value has two elements (possibly more). I would like to iterate over each value-pair for each key and delete those values-pairs that meet some criteria. Here for instance I would like to delete the second value pair for the key A; that is: `('Ok!', '0')`:

```
myDict = {'A': [('Yes!', '8'), ('Ok!', '0')], 'B': [('No!', '2')]}
```

to:

```
myDict = {'A': [('Yes!', '8')], 'B': [('No!', '2')]}
```

I can iterate over the dictionary by key or value, but can't figure out how I delete a specific value.

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Please add your code then it will be easy for us to help

Comment: You can use `pop`. In your example `myDict['A'].pop(1)` .

Comment: you can use `remove`. for example `myDict['A'].remove( ('Ok!', '0') )`

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code like this:

```
myDict = {'A': [('Yes!', '8'), ('Ok!', '0')], 'B': [('No!', '2')]}
for v in myDict.values():
    if ('Ok!', '0') in v:
        v.remove(('Ok!', '0'))
print(myDict)
```

Comment: Minor note: If the `list`s might be long and removals semi-common, it would be better to do `try: v.remove(('Ok!', '0'))`, `except ValueError: pass`, so you're only iterating the `list` once, not once to check, and a second time to remove. Also, if you're on Python 2, use `.itervalues()` or `.viewvalues()` over `.values()`, to avoid creating an unnecessary temporary `list` of the values; on Py2, `.values()` is equivalent to Py2.7's `.viewvalues()`, so it avoids the temporaries automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

```
myDict = {'A': [('Yes!', '8'), ('Ok!', '0')], 'B': [('No!', '2')]}
del myDict['A'][1]
print(myDict)
```

Explanation :

myDict['A'] - It will grab the Value w.r.t Key A

myDict['A'][1] - It will grab first index tuple

del myDict['A'][1] - now this will delete that tuple

Answer (score -3):

```
myDict = {'A': [('Yes!', '8'), ('Ok!', '0')], 'B': [('No!', '2')]}
for v in myDict.values():
    for x in v:
        if x[0] == 'Ok!' and x[1] == '0':
            v.remove(x)
print(myDic)
```

Comment: This is a minor change to the response of @Em L . With this modification, it is possible to check for a condition on the first element of a member of all values.

Comment: The element to be found was value pair `('Ok!', '0')`. If checking just first element for `'Ok!'`, also other tuplets like `('Ok!', '1')` will match. Therefore, this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @AminBa rather than trying to explain your answer in the comments, please use the `edit` button under your answer and modify it to include the information that you have put in the comments (and then delete the comments)