# How to remove a particular value from the list of values using Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to remove the particular value from the list of key. I got Type error. I wrote function to add and remove the key. need to remove a particular value from the key

```
class my_dict(dict):    
    def add(self, key, value):
        self.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

    def remove_key(self, key):
        del self[key]

    #Error part
    def remove_value(self,key,value):
        for value in dict.values():
            if v in value:
                value.remove(v)

dict_obj = my_dict()
dict_obj.add('key1', 'value1')
dict_obj.add('key2', 'value2')
dict_obj.add('key1', 'value3')
print(dict_obj)  

>>{'key1': ['value1', 'value3'], 'key2': ['value2']}


dict_obj.remove_value('key1','value3')
print(dict_obj)
```

My Out

```
TypeError: descriptor 'values' of 'dict' object needs an argument
```

Desired Output

```
>>{'key1': ['value1'], 'key2': ['value2']}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python how to delete a specific value from a dictionary key with multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350527/python-how-to-delete-a-specific-value-from-a-dictionary-key-with-multiple-values)

Comment: Try doing `self.values()` instead of `dict.values()`? Or at least `dict.values(self)`. The method `values()` is an instance method on `dict`, and you're trying to call it like a class method.

Comment: @green i change to  self.values() , NameError: name 'v' is not defined

Comment: @maws Double-check what you've named your variables. What did you tell python `v` was supposed to be, and where did you do so?

Comment: you want to remove it from `self[key].value` if `value in self[key]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple problems in:

```
def remove_value(self,key,value):
    for value in dict.values():
        if v in value:
            value.remove(v)
```

1. You used `dict.values()`, not `self.values()`; the former is trying to call `dict.values` with no `dict` instance to operate on
2. You named two things `value`, and one replaces the other (while using `v` without ever naming anything `v`)

Minimal fix would be:

```
def remove_value(self,key,v):  # Name argument v to match test and remove
    for value in self.values():  # Call values on self
        if v in value:
            value.remove(v)
```

Slightly more readable fix (that would also limit removal to the specified `key`, which I'm guessing was the intent, since you receive a `key` argument) would be:

```
def remove_value(self, key, toremove):
    try:
        self[key].remove(toremove)
    except (KeyError, ValueError):
        pass
    else:
        if not self[key]:
            del self[key]
```

Remove the `try`/`except` block if you want non-existent keys or values to raise `KeyError` or `ValueError` respectively. Remove the `else` block if you want to leave a key in place even if all values are removed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove it from `self[key].value` if `value in self[key]`:

```
def remove_value(self,key,value):
    if value in self.get(key, []):
        self[key].remove(value)
```

But similar to your [previous related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57362194/1467082), this seems like you'd be better suited using `defaultdict` than trying to monkeypatch your own dict-like object.

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(list)
mydict['key1'].append('value1')
mydict['key1'].append('value3')
mydict['key2'].append('value2')
if 'value3' in mydict['key1']:
    mydict['key1'].remove('value3')
```

Comment: Note: This will raise `KeyError` if the `key` in question doesn't exist; the test prevents the `ValueError`, but actually triggers the `KeyError`. You could make it `if value in self.get(key, ()):` to avoid the `KeyError` as well. You also left off a `:` at the end of the `if` check.